# Chipmunk: How to Update shape?

Tags: chipmunk

How can I update Space in chupmunk My Code is:

```
// left
    shape1 = cpSegmentShapeNew(edge, cpvzero, cpv(0.0f, size.height), 0.0f);
    shape1->u = 0.1f; // minimal friction on the ground
    shape1->e = 0.7f;
    cpSpaceAddStaticShape(_space, shape1); // a body can be represented by multiple shapes

    // top
    shape2 = cpSegmentShapeNew(edge, cpvzero, cpv(size.width, 0.0f), 0.0f);
    shape2->u = 0.1f;
    shape2->e = 0.7f;
    cpSpaceAddStaticShape(_space, shape2);

    // right
    shape3 = cpSegmentShapeNew(edge, cpv(size.width, 0.0f), cpv(size.width, size.height), 0.0f);
    shape3->u = 0.1f;
    shape3->e = 0.7f;
    cpSpaceAddStaticShape(_space, shape3);

    // bottom
    shape4 = cpSegmentShapeNew(edge, cpv(0.0f, size.height), cpv(size.width, size.height), 0.0f);
    shape4->u = 0.1f;
    shape4->e = 0.7f;
    cpSpaceAddStaticShape(_space, shape4);
```

if ball touch the Bottom shape[image: Ball touch] like this[image: after collosion] ball go up but the bottom shape is remove and display green line that want i do but i dont know how to remove shape from body. anyone suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cpSpaceRemoveStaticShape(_space, shape4);
```

Comment: How is this an answer. This may have worked but without an explanation to what it is, it is not a good answer at all. -1 will remove when includes explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So three things.

1) The cpSpace[Add|Remove]StaticShape() functions are deprecated, and you should be using the cpSpace[Add|Remove]Shape() functions instead.

2) As the last answer stated, cpSpaceAddShape() will add a shape to a space. If you want to remove it you call cpSpaceRemoveShape(). There's really nothing more to it than that.

3) Chipmunk doesn't do any graphics, so if you want to draw a green line you need to use whatever functionality provided by your graphics or rendering library.